# Angular ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I have a task to implement a wrapper around a component so that it's seamless to use with Angular forms so I'm implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. The underlying component is open source and peeking at it I realized it's also implementing `ControlValueAccessor`

It seems silly for my wrapper to reimplement the interface, but I do need the wrapper to set some component defaults. Is there a way to take avoid reimplementing `ControlValueAccessor` while keeping the wrapper?

This is what I use to set the defaults for `ngx-quill`:

```
class MyTextEditor {
  public ngOnInit() {
    // icons configuration
    var icons = Quill.import('ui/icons');
    icons['bold'] = '<i class="fa fa-bold" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['italic'] = '<i class="fa fa-italic" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['underline'] = '<i class="fa fa-underline" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['image'] = '<i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['code'] = '<i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>';


    const blockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');
    blockEmbed.blotName = 'divider';
    blockEmbed.tagName = 'hr';
    Quill.register(blockEmbed);
  }
}
```

Comment: At the end of the day the component on which you slap ngModel is the one that needs to provide the accessor — it doesn't have to implement it itself, however. So if you can get it from elsewhere that would be fine. This isn't likely realistic, and more likely you just need to implement one that forwards to the underlying component which is rather easy anyway.

Comment: Side note: wrapper components make for an unflexible API. If you can implement the wrapper using composition (content projection) instead such that the user retains access to the underlying component you'd both be more flexible API-wise and rid of this question. This may not (easily) be possible depending on what you want to do, though.

Comment: @IngoBürk wrapper components often increase flexibility as you can provide a consistent API within your app, even if you swap out the underlying or if the underlying changes, it's an update in one place rather than an update in N places.

Comment: I've come across wrappers that forward a lot of inputs and outputs much more often than I had to exchange entire underlying UI frameworks of apps. I'd stick with my point that in general composition is preferable (when possible). But if you have full access to the code and can change it whenever you need to, it won't matter as much. Wrappers can be necessary and/or useful, but quite often they happen purely out of inexperience on how to do it better.

Comment: @IngoBürk I'm open to a better way of doing this. I've added the code that sets the defaults; these defaults need to be used by any code using this text editor ideally without  re-implementation

Comment: The code is largely incomplete and I haven't worked with quill before, but given that this seems to be global configuration I'd assume you can do this globally rather than per component instance, eliminating the need of a wrapper. Or it could be done as a directive instead. ngx-quill also has an interface for global configuration, not sure what you need is available there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `ngx-quill` library but consider extending the Component instead of warping it as demonstrated below:

```js
class MyTextEditor extends QuillEditor {

  public ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    
    // icons configuration
    var icons = Quill.import('ui/icons');
    icons['bold'] = '<i class="fa fa-bold" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['italic'] = '<i class="fa fa-italic" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['underline'] = '<i class="fa fa-underline" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['image'] = '<i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    icons['code'] = '<i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>';


    const blockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');
    blockEmbed.blotName = 'divider';
    blockEmbed.tagName = 'hr';
    Quill.register(blockEmbed);
  }
}
```

In addition  you can set custom configuration when imorting `QuillModule` using `forRoot` method as below:

```js
QuillModule.forRoot({
  toolbar: [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

    [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
    [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
    [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
    [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button

    ['link', 'image', 'video']                         // link and image, video
  ]
})
```

Comment: I like the inheritance approach, but how can I have the child component use the same template/styles as its parent?

Comment: `@charmelean` why do you need to inherit style? I've got the impression that you only want to pass some configurations

Answer (score 0):

A way that I found to wrap some form component and keep the functionality of `ReactiveForms` without implement the `ControlValueAccessor` is the following:

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-comp',
  template: `
    <child-comp controlName="myReactiveFormComponentName"></child-comp>
  `,
})
```

In the child component add this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="controlName" />
  `,
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() controlName:string

}
```

With that you could just pass the name of the control from the parent and assign in the child to your input.

Comment: This breaks the abstraction the CVA is supposed to offer, however, and for example renders you unable to use ngModel instead. This is fine for components built specifically for a big form etc, but for reusable wrappers I'd strongly advise against this.

Comment: I think that always depends on your use case, I use this a lot to wrap some input that have specific UI design, so I wrap the design around the input and reuse in my app. Probably for specific behavior of your control would be better to use CVA